# How to compile a dll in a project and use it like a reference?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I'm using .Net framework 2.0 and I've been searching on how to include a .dll in my project. I want this dll to be compliled in the final .exe, but I don't know how. When I add it to my project like any file, my classes can't access the functions because they need a `[Dll Import]`. And when I add it as a reference, it's being pasted in the `Release` folder.

Is there a way to access my dll without recoding every function or use it as a reference?

Comment: Why do you want the dll it inside the exe?

Comment: Why don't you want to use it as a reference?

Comment: Why don't you want it in the debug / release folders, i.e you don't want to deploy it. There are ways of achieving that effect, but they are either fragile, or require a significant amount of effort. Oh and they will require effort to differentiate between debug, build and deploy.

Comment: Thanks @TonyHopkinson for the help. I will look for more information about deploying an application. Btw, I really don't know why I got downvoted...

Comment: Wasn't me, but someone's likely to when a questioner leaves so many questions they could answer, unanswered. Think of it like getting an email from a user about your app. "I clicked on the button and it gave me an error, please fix". What button, wheant error , how and when, 0perhaps even why would be good... Asking good questions is at least as useful a skill as being able to answer them, so condier the -1 a learning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are searching for is called ILmerge.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx